# Excel VBA - Update unique record on multiple Rows after inserted to table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to update data in Table1 after it's been added. The way I add the data currently is in the code below. I do this through a user form that when runs calculates the difference between two dates and then uses that value to create an equal number of rows through a loop.

**Adding Data Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call sflicker

Dim ArriveDate As Date
Dim DepartDate As Date
Dim DateRangeLength As Long
Dim LoopCounter As Long
Dim RowAfterLast As Long

Set Dbm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DBM")

ArriveDate = CDate(Me.Arrive_Date.Value)
DepartDate = CDate(Me.Depart_Date.Value)

DateRangeLength = (DepartDate - ArriveDate)

With DBM

        For LoopCounter = 1 To DateRangeLength
        RowAfterLast = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If LoopCounter = 1 Then

            .Range("A" & RowAfterLast).Value = ID           'ok
            .Range("B" & RowAfterLast).Value = ArriveDate   'ok
            .Range("C" & RowAfterLast).Value = LoopCounter  'ok
            .Range("D" & RowAfterLast).Value = 1            'ok
            .Range("E" & RowAfterLast).Value = ArriveDate   'ok
            .Range("F" & RowAfterLast).Value = DepartDate   'ok

        Else
            .Range("A" & RowAfterLast).Value = ID           'ok
            .Range("B" & RowAfterLast).Value = ArriveDate + (LoopCounter - 1) ' Accrul Date
            .Range("C" & RowAfterLast).Value = LoopCounter  'ok
            .Range("D" & RowAfterLast).Value = 2            'ok
            .Range("E" & RowAfterLast).Value = ArriveDate   'ok
            .Range("F" & RowAfterLast).Value = DepartDate   'ok
        End If
    Next LoopCounter
End With

Add_Renter.Hide

End Sub
```

After I run this. I'm looking for a way to update the data from cells in the workbook. e.g. ArriveDate = A1 and Depart Date = B1. If I change A1 and B1 then run command (macro), I would like the table to update the existing records.

I've thought that if I delete the records based on the unique ID and run the code again - it might do what I need.  Looking for some guidance. Appreciate the help.

I've tried merging this code with no luck.

```
row_number = 0
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets("DBM").Range("A" & row_number)
    If item_in_review = Sheets("Bookings").Range("G31").Text Then

                    Sheets("Bookings").Range("G37").Value = Sheets("DBM").Range("B" & row_number)
                    Sheets("Bookings").Range("N37").Value = Sheets("DBM").Range("C" & row_number)


     End If

Loop Until item_in_review = ""
```

Comment: Could you rewrite the question with step by step description of what is done by who, where you whant the data updated, what needs to happen when, after what?

Comment: Yes sure, sorry if I was a bit pushy... I have removed my comments...

Comment: @AndrasDorko No problem. Sorry it's not more clear. I'll try to ask my question a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tries, I figured how to delete the initial entries by working backwards up the table. Here is a sample of the code used.

Sub Update_Record_Click()

```
Dim DateRangeLength As Long
Dim LoopCounter As Long
Dim RowAfterLast As Long
Dim ArriveDate As Date
Dim DepartDate As Date
Dim BookID As Long
Dim Book As Worksheet
Dim DBA As Worksheet
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long

Set Book = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bookings")
Set CRT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CRT")
Set DBA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DBA")

BookID = CLng(Book.Range("G35").Value)
ArriveDate = CDate(Book.Range("G41").Value)
DepartDate = CDate(Book.Range("N41").Value)

'Delete first records that were inputed

With DBA

FirstRow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

For Lrow = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1

With .Cells(Lrow, "A")

    If Not IsError(.Value) Then

        If .Value = Book.Range("G35").Value Then .EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    End With

    Next Lrow

End With

'Start Re Add after record delete
DateRangeLength = (DepartDate - ArriveDate)

With DBA
    For LoopCounter = 1 To DateRangeLength
        RowAfterLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If LoopCounter = 1 Then

            .Range("A" & RowAfterLast).Value = BookID
            .Range("B" & RowAfterLast).Value = ArriveDate
            .Range("C" & RowAfterLast).Value = LoopCounter
            .Range("D" & RowAfterLast).Value = 1
            .Range("F" & RowAfterLast).Value = ArriveDate
            .Range("G" & RowAfterLast).Value = DepartDate


        Else
            .Range("A" & RowAfterLast).Value = BookID
            .Range("B" & RowAfterLast).Value = ArriveDate + (LoopCounter - 1)
            .Range("C" & RowAfterLast).Value = LoopCounter
            .Range("D" & RowAfterLast).Value = 2
            .Range("F" & RowAfterLast).Value = ArriveDate
            .Range("G" & RowAfterLast).Value = DepartDate


        End If
    Next LoopCounter
End With

Calculate

End Sub
```

Hope this helps anyone looking to update multiple records in a table in excel with VBA.